# How to start cd-horizontal-timeline from the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery

We've inherited a website and the previous web developers have copied the codyhouse horizontal timeline.

The problem is our client has asked for the timeline to start from the end. As in the last element should be shown first.

The previous web developers have seemed to copy the code exactly straight from this code pen.

https://codepen.io/shvvffle/pen/BzZGAd

https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html

I've tried to modify the following function:

```
function setDatePosition(timelineComponents, min) {
    for (i = 0; i < timelineComponents['timelineDates'].length; i++) { 
        var distance = daydiff(timelineComponents['timelineDates'][0], timelineComponents['timelineDates'][i]),
            distanceNorm = Math.round(distance/timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse']) + 2;
        timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].eq(i).css('left', distanceNorm*min+'px');
    }
}
```

to trigger on page load and send the slider to the end, but I'm not sure what 'timelineComponents' is referring to.

The code is exactly the same as the code pen code, we just need the slider to start from the last position on load. Does anyone have any ideas? This code pen is not mine so please don't edit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add class `selected` to your desired `a[data-date]`, save it to some variable, for example `$my_lovely_element`,
2. Give a name to anonymous function that is being passed in line `timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].on(...),` something like `onNavClick`,
3. Call `onNavClick` in next line after `var timelineTotWidth = setTimelineWidth(...)`, like this: `onNavClick.call($my_lovely_element, new Event("click"))`

If you wanna get rid of animation put into use some class that will control `transition`

Btw, i didn't get the line `I'm not sure what 'timelineComponents' is referring to`. What do you mean? You have the whole code, you can put it in any IDE and it will tell you what `timelineComponents` mean. Basic Ctrl+F:timelineComponents will work too